# How to center a Button using a FormLayout in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

How can I position a `Button` (vertically) at the center using a `FormLayout` (see [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html))? Using:

```
final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
button.setText("Button");

final FormData layoutData = new FormData();
layoutData.top = new FormAttachment(50);
layoutData.left = new FormAttachment(0);
layoutData.right = new FormAttachment(100);
button.setLayoutData(layoutData);
```

I end up with

[image]

Which is not surprising, since I told it to put the top of the button at the center (`layoutData.top = new FormAttachment(50);`). How can I instead put the center of the button at the center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify an offset with the constructor:

```
new FormAttachment(int numerator, int offset)
```

Looks like this:

[image]

You can compute the offset using:

```
final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
button.setText("Button");

final FormData layoutData = new FormData();

/* Compute the offset */
int offset = -button.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y / 2;

/* Create the FormAttachment */
layoutData.top = new FormAttachment(50, offset);
layoutData.left = new FormAttachment(0);
layoutData.right = new FormAttachment(100);
button.setLayoutData(layoutData);
```

Comment: This will not work if the window is resized. I guess you'll need some sort of a resize listener and then re-calculate the offset. Oh well, it's probably easier just to use a GridLayout with single grid and GridData(GridData.CENTER, GridData.CENTER, true, true).

Comment: @NeemePraks No, you don't need to listen to resize events. The `FormAttachement` uses percentages. You would only need to update it if the height of the `Button` changes, which it normally doesn't.